# How can I send a property of an object by a prop without it being defined yet?

Tags: reactjs, react-props

It happens that I have an object with three properties that each contains an array, I need to pass those properties to another component, but the detail is that the object has not yet been added to a hook or a variable, it would be added later.

How could I do this, I add a code in stackblitz of the error that I get.

[code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-z7has8)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Conditional Rendering](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html)

Common pattern is to conditionally render children when data is available.

```
export default function App() {
  const [object, setObject] = useState({}); // provide initial state!!

  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      setObject({
        0: [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        1: [2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
        2: [3, 3, 3, 3, 3]
      });
    }, 3000);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      {Object.values(object).length ? (
        <Component1 object={object[0]} />
      ) : (
        "loading..."
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit sweet-cherry-eumzr]